# Copying a value from POST into a variable

Tags: php, post

In a page I have a form that submits with Post method. In another page I'm just trying to retreive and echo those values. If I just:

```
var_dump($_POST)
```

I see every value I entered in the form.

If I do something like:

```
echo $_POST['name'];
echo $_POST['surname'];
echo $_POST['telephone'];
```

I see the correct values.

But if, at the beginning of the page, use:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$surname = $_POST['surname'];
$telephone = $_POST['telephone'];

echo $name . ' ' . $surname . ' ' . $telephone;
```

I notice that for example `name` and `telephone` are always empty.

HTML form:

```
<form id="dom_com_sci" class="form" name="dom_com_sci" action="./ricevuta-fiscale-2convention.php" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" target="_self" style="height: 2200px; width: 619px;">

    <p>
        <label for="name">name:</label>
        <input id="name" class="focus capitalize" name="name" type="text" size="26" value="" maxlength="70" placeholder="es. Mario" autocomplete="off" />
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="surname">surname:</label>
        <input id="surname" class="focus capitalize" name="surname" type="text" size="26" value="" maxlength="70" placeholder="es. Rossi" autocomplete="off" />
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="telephone">telephone:</label>
        <input id="telephone" class="focus capitalize" name="telephone" type="text" size="26" value="" maxlength="70" placeholder="es. Rossi" autocomplete="off" />
    </p>

    <input type="submit" name="Send" value="Send" tabindex="34" />

</form>
```

The php script on the result page:

```
<?php   
    require_once('./function/generic_function.php');

    if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == "Send") {

        $surname= $_POST['surname'];
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
    }
?>
```

generic_function.php:

```
<?php

    function replace($stringa) {
        $stringa_r = str_replace('\\','',$stringa);
        return $stringa_r;
    }

    function accesso($percorso,$opzione = "N") {
        ($opzione == "Y") ? $blank = "target=_blank" : $blank = "";
        if(isset($_SESSION['access_level']) && $_SESSION['access_level'] > 1 && isset($_SESSION['logged']) && $_SESSION['logged'] == 1 && isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
            print('href="'.$percorso.'"'.$blank);
        } else {
            print('href="'.$dir.'access.php"');
        } 
    }

?>
```

Comment: Post your real code.  Also, what happens if you echo the $_POST values both before and after you do the echo $name... line

Comment: are you posting form on this page?

Comment: nothing wrong with the code which you just posted here. mistake is some where else.

Comment: @steve he is getting the result with echo $_post thats what he is saying, so its weird. That he cant use variable. its not the full code i am assuming this.

Comment: Can you show us the code to your html form?

Comment: Why people are asking for the form code?? as he himself is saying he is getting the value for var_dump($_post) and for the echo $_post['name']; so he getting the value from the form. I think its not the same code which he is using at that page. as this code work fine

Comment: If you copy/paste this code into an IDE, it is obvious that there are some quotes missing. So use a decent IDE to avoid spending time on typos.

Comment: @Konst read the comment on Arif answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing on quote `(')` in these line

```
$surname= $_POST['surname];
$name = $_POST['name];
$telephone = $_POST['telephone];
```

it should be this

```
$surname= $_POST['surname'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$telephone = $_POST['telephone'];

<?php
//error_reporting($level=NULL);

?>





<form id="dom_com_sci" class="form" name="dom_com_sci" action="" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" target="_self" >

    <p>
        <label for="name">name:</label>
        <input id="name" class="focus capitalize" name="name" type="text" size="26" value="" maxlength="70" placeholder="es. Mario" autocomplete="off" />
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="surname">surname:</label>
        <input id="surname" class="focus capitalize" name="surname" type="text" size="26" value="" maxlength="70" placeholder="es. Rossi" autocomplete="off" />
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="telephone">telephone:</label>
        <input id="telephone" class="focus capitalize" name="telephone" type="text" size="26" value="" maxlength="70" placeholder="es. Rossi" autocomplete="off" />
    </p>

   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" tabindex="34" />

</form>
<?php   
    //require_once('./function/generic_function.php');

    if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == "submit") {



        $surname= $_POST['surname'];
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
        echo $name . ' ' . $surname . ' ' . $telephone;
    }
?>
```

**Comment::** To style your form. You can put it inside the div and than can give that div style. 
Thanks let me know it work or not.

Comment: It is just an error of rewriting while pasting here the code. I had to translate variables' name from italian to english so I missed a quote! In the real code it is correct

Comment: @misiMe see the updated answer and let me know. It worked or not. I checked it before i posted it. so it should work. But in any case it does not work let me know. Thanks

Comment: @misiMe is your problem solved or not. if not let me know. I will post the same code which i used to help you. And that code work. Thanks like i wil post the whole code instead of telling you to change this line and that line. Thanks

Comment: @misiMe see the updated answer i add one echo line just to show that its working. enter some dummy data and see the result and let me know

Comment: @misiMe Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61596/discussion-between-arif-suhail-123-and-misime).